# Java Generic classes assignability

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes:

```
    public interface ModelObject {
    }
    public interface Resource {
    }
    public interface Transformer <F,T>{
    }
    public interface WrapperFactory {
        Transformer<Resource, Wrap<? extends ModelObject>> createMapper();
    }
    public class Wrap<E extends ModelObject> {

    }

    public class AbstractBaseTransformer<F,T> implements Transformer<F,T> {
    }
    public class ConcreteModel implements ModelObject {

    }
    public class ConcreteTransformer extends AbstractBaseTransformer<Resource, Wrap<ConcreteModel>> {

    }
    public class ConcreteFactory implements WrapperFactory {

        @Override
        public Transformer<Resource, Wrap<? extends ModelObject>> createMapper() {
            return new ConcreteTransformer();
        }
    }
```

The ConcreteFactory doesn't compile stating that ConcreteTransformer is incompatible with returned

```
Transformer<Resource, Wrap<? extends ModelObject>>
```

I can't see what's wrong here. ConcreteTransformer binds 1st parameter to Resource (same as expected) while binding 2nd parameter to:

```
Wrap<ConcreteModel>
```

which should bind to:

```
Wrap<? extends ModelObject>
```

as ConcreteModel implements it.

Comment: Is this happening in Eclipse or in the JDK? The Eclipse compiler contains a few bugs.

Comment: @dsmog The correct terminology is "generics" (Java), "template classes" (A syntactically similar but conceptually very different concept in C++).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simpler version, to narrow down the issue:

```
interface ModelObject {}
class ConcreteModel implements ModelObject {}

class Wrap<E extends ModelObject> {}
class SomeGeneric<T> {}

class Simple {
    public SomeGeneric<Wrap<? extends ModelObject>> m() {
        return new SomeGeneric<Wrap<ConcreteModel>>();
    }
}
```

does not compile either.

Your problem is that a [`SomeGeneric<Wrap<ConcreteModel>>` is not a `SomeGeneric<Wrap<? extends ModelObject>>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p).

Answer (score 2):

`Wrap<ConcreteModel>` is a subtype of `Wrap<? extends ModelObject>`? Yes.

`Transformer<Resource, Wrap<ConcreteModel>>` is a subtype of `Transformer<Resource, Wrap<? extends ModelObject>>`? No.

It's the same as:

`String` is a subtype of `Object`? Yes.

`List<String>` is a subtype of `List<Object>`? No.

Basically, for parameterized types to be compatible, if the top-level parameter is not wildcard, then the parameters must match *exactly*. In your case, the top-level parameter is not wildcard, and the parameters don't match exactly.

What you probably wanted instead was

`Transformer<Resource, ? extends Wrap<? extends ModelObject>>`

Answer (score 0):

A `Wrap<ConcreteModel>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Wrap<? extends ModelObject>`. But the matter here is more complex.

Assume you have a `ArrayList<Wrap<? extends ModelObject>> list`. When you have such a type, it means that you can add a `Wrap<ConcreteModel>` to the list, but it also means that you can add a `Wrap<ModelObject>` to it. In brief, it means you have a list, that can contain a Wrap of anything that can be cast to a `ModelObject`.

On the other side, having a `ArrayList<Wrap<ConcreteModel>> list` means you can only add `Wrap<ConcreteModel>`s to it, while a `Wrap<ModelObject>` cannot be added to it, because the list can only contain wrapped `ConcreteModel`s, and a wrapped `ModelObject` is not a wrapped `ConcreteModel` nor it can be cast to be one.

This is exactly your case. You declared your `createMapper()` method to return a `Transformer<Resource, Wrap<? extends ModelObject>>`. This means that the second argument of the returned Transformer must be able to be any subclass of `ModelObject`, including `ModelObject` itself. On the contrary, you are trying to return a `Transformer<Resource, Wrap<ConcreteModel>>`.

The compiler needs to enforce this because `Transformer<F, T>` could declare a method:

```
void myMethod(F fObject, T tObject);
```

If that was the case, the method `myMethod` of an object of type `Transformer<Resource, Wrap<? extends ModelObject>>` would accept an object of type `ModelObject` as its second argument. On the other side, the same method, in a object of type `Transformer<Resource, Wrap<ConcreteModel>>` **cannot** accept a `ModelObject` as its second argument.